Database replication - multi hop
We currently have a SQL 2016 database replicating to a SQL 2012 database and we are upgrading our SQL 2016 instance to SQL 2019. According to the compatibility documentation, replication between the versions would no longer be possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility
We are unable to update the SQL 2012 instance so I wondered if a "multi hop" approach would work i.e. replication from SQL 2012 to a new SQL 2016 and then replication from the new SQL 2016 instance to the SQL 2019 instance.


I wondered if a "multi hop" approach would work i.e. replication from SQL 2012 to a new SQL 2016 and then replication from the new SQL 2016 instance to the SQL 2019 instance.

Yes, this is allowed.
A Subscriber is allowed to also be a Publisher. The same rules apply regarding SQL Server version compatibility between the Subscriber that's acting as a Publisher to another Subscriber. You can only use Transactional or Merge replication when mixing republishers.
You'll probably find the docs on Republish Data of interest.
